# Apex Array Slice

Tags: apex, array

Sometimes I like to use a `Queueable` to perform work on a list of Ids or sObjects over the heaver `Batchable` Interface.

However, to do this, we need a very solid implementation of an Array `slice` method.

Most other programming languages have a native `slice` method, but `Apex` does not.

While I have written my own version of `slice` and it's working fine, I would be interested in hearing about other implementations of `slice` - the more efficient the better.

My version is in this Utilities class on github [here](https://gist.github.com/rapsacnz/53e87c4ee90c8b9ced4eaa396661fe8c)

It's modelled after the `Javascript` version described on the mozilla site [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

I would expect that the usage and output be similar to this:

```
String[] arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
String[] sliced = Utilities.slice(arr,1, 3);

System.debug(arr);      // ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
System.debug(sliced);   // ['one', 'two']
```

Comment: How one and two are returned while providing 1,3 in the `slice` method call?

Comment: Guys thanks for giving this some though - both of these techniques look very good - fox's for it's much safer implementation and adrian's for taking a different approach. I'm having trouble deciding who I should award the accept to.

Comment: @Mahmood the numbers are start and end values for the array

Comment: Ok the results are in! sfdcfox - I added a small change to your array `temp[i-startIndex] = ary[i];` adrian - I added bounds checking so that it was compariable with sfdcfox's version (not that this mattered really, the time is all in the loop anyway.  Adrian median time was about 15ms and Sfdc median time was 23ms. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a pattern that seems relatively efficient and easier to understand.

```
public static List<Object> slice(List<Object> input, Integer ge, Integer l)
{
    List<Object> output = input.clone();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < ge; i++) output.remove(0);
    Integer elements = l - ge;
    while (output.size() > elements) output.remove(elements);
    return output;
}
```

If you want to support negative index, just add these lines at the beginning of the method:

```
if (ge < 0) ge += input.size();
if (l < 0) l += input.size();
```

And running it through this script yields the proper input/output combos:

```
List<String> data = new List<String> { 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Lemon', 'Apple', 'Mango' };
List<String> sliced = (List<String>)slice(data, 1, 3);

system.debug(data); // (Banana, Orange, Lemon, Apple, Mango)
system.debug(sliced); // (Orange, Lemon)

List<String> data = new List<String> { 'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three' };
List<String> sliced = (List<String>)slice(data, 1, 3);

system.debug(data); // (zero, one, two, three)
system.debug(sliced); // (one, two)
```

Comment: This version assumes that ge and l are within legal ranges, and also doesn't act like the JavaScript version it was meant to emulate.

Comment: I'm getting the same input/output combos as the OP and linked documentation.

Comment: Yours was a little quicker than @sfdcfox 's - both were better than mine.

Comment: The documentation allows for negative indexes, which specify an offset from the end rather than the beginning of the list.

Comment: @AdrianLarson What about slice(data, -3, -1)?

Comment: The same strategy.

Answer (score 11):

While it's not a bad start, I can think of a number of problems:

- No bounds checks are provided
- Only Id and SObject are supported
- SObject version returns generic list, does not support upsert
- Has debug statements
- Is overly verbose
- Thrashes the heap more than necessary

Here's a version that closer to what I'd include in a library (which I'm working on), but feel free to study and borrow this code.

```
// Edit: now behaves better in more cases
public static Object[] slice(Object[] ary, Integer first, Integer last) {
    Object[] res = ary.clone(), temp;
    Integer size = ary.size(),
        startIndex = Math.min(size, Math.max(-1, first<0? size+first: first)),
        endIndex = Math.min(size, Math.max(-1, last<0? size+last: last-1)),
        offset = Math.max(-1, endIndex-startIndex);
    temp = new Object[offset+1];
    for(Integer h = 0, i = startIndex, j = endIndex; i <= j; ) {
        temp[h++] = ary[i++];
    }
    res.clear();
    res.addAll(temp);
    return res;
}
```

This version supports all generic lists, not just Id or SObject, returns a list of the same type as the original (so supports upsert), and has very similar behavior to JavaScript.

Comment: @AdrianLarson can't decide which version I like best, so I'm going to time it.

Comment: It'd be nice to see exactly where Adrian is getting his speed gains - all I can currently see is the overall script time. I suppose its the internal efficiency of the built in `remove` method that beats our array element dereferencing technique

Comment: @CasparHarmer My version behaves "more" like splice (handles negative values more or less as specified), but it is still glitchy. Adrian's version does a bit more heap allocation but less checking. It's really just a matter of how close you need the behavior to be. Without the negative indexes, I'd expect my version to be at least as fast.

Comment: @sfdcfox I don't think your answer works at all. Try slice(arr, 1, 2) and you'll get out of bounds exception... Also, it seems to start from 1, not 0 (I don't think that's how usual s(p)lice works) :|

Comment: @dzh You're right, it was more back-of-a-napkin implementation. However, since you've made mention, I've (hopefully) addressed all of the issues. It should now be a lot closer to the intended behavior and removes the out-of-bound errors.

Answer (score 8):

There's already some good answers here, but I figured I'd throw my hat into the ring anyways.

In my approach, I've tried to stay as close to the Javascript versions as possible.

The JS `slice` is a variable arity function that makes use of up to the first two arguments it is provided, so I provided three methods for my `Slice` class with 0, 1, and 2 parameters respectively.

Also, JS doesn't have integers, and all numbers are floating point, so I defined my method parameters as `Decimal`s, and rounded with them the `CEILING` round mode; meaning that `-0.5` is taken to be `0`.

I wanted to name the parameters `begin` and `end` to stay inline with the mdn page, but those are unfortunately reserved (for future use) keywords.

I also went with a more OO approach instead of using static utility methods, but that should be easy enough to change if you want to do it the other way instead.

```
public class Slice {

    private list<Object> olist;

    public Slice(list<Object> olist){
        this.olist = olist;
    }   

    public list<Object> slice(){
        return olist.clone();
    }   

    public list<Object> slice(Decimal x_begin){
        Integer start = x_begin == NULL ? 0 : (Integer) x_begin.round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
        return commonSlice(start,olist.size());
    }   

    public list<Object> slice(Decimal x_begin, Decimal x_end){
        Integer start  = x_begin == NULL ? 0            : (Integer) x_begin.round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
        Integer finish = x_end   == NULL ? olist.size() : (Integer) x_end.round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
        return commonSlice(start, finish);
    }   

    private list<Object> commonSlice(Integer x_begin, Integer x_end){
        list<Object> ret = new list<Object>();
        x_begin = x_begin < 0 ? olist.size() + x_begin : x_begin ;
        x_end   = x_end   < 0 ? olist.size() + x_end   : x_end   ;   
        Integer maxIndex = olist.size();
        while (x_begin < maxIndex && x_begin < x_end){
            ret.add(olist[x_begin]);
            x_begin++;
        }
        return ret;
    }   


}
```

Some examples:

```
list<Integer> ilist = new list<Integer>{1,2,3,4,5};
Slice s = new Slice(ilist);
system.debug(s.slice());       // (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
system.debug(s.slice(-.5,20)); // (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
system.debug(s.slice(.5));     // (2, 3, 4, 5)
system.debug(s.slice(1));      // (2, 3, 4, 5)
system.debug(s.slice(2,-2));   // (3)
system.debug(s.slice(2,-3));   // ()
system.debug(s.slice(7,100));  // ()
system.debug(s.slice(NULL,2)); // (1, 2)
```

Comment: That's a great answer - thanks for adding it martin! Very clean and encapusulated.