# i need to split larger set list into smaller chunks

Tags: apex, community

i have a requirement, where i am holding list(1000) of email address into one set, and with that i need to split them in to 100 in each sublist and make queryString need to perform sosl query.

```
 set<integer> nms= new set<integer>();
string str;
integer setindex=0;
for(integer i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    nms.add(i);
}

system.debug('set==>'+nms.size());

set<integer> temp= new set<integer>();
for(integer i=0;i<nms.size()/10;i++)
{

    for(integer j=0;j<30;j++ )
    { 
        str=str +string.valueOf(j)+' or ';
        setindex++;
        //sosl

    }

   if(setindex== nms.size())
       break;
   system.debug('set==>'+str);

}
```

can any one help me fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: similar to: [Apex Array Slice](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179786/apex-array-slice/)

Comment: Why do you need to slice your array? If you're expecting less than 2000 rows, you can do it all at once.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good application of the `slice` function that I posted a question about earlier this week.

I recommend using the [version](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179789/550) provided by Adrian or the [version](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179790/550) provided by sfdcfox.

To extend this (rather than just linking the question) you also need to divide your list into sets of 100.

You would implement this like so:

```
String[] yourEmailList;
for (Integer i = 0; i< 9; i++){
  Integer a = i*100;
  Integer b = (i+1)*100;
  String[] emailSublist = Utility.slice(yourEmailList,a,b);
  //perform sosl
}
```